# How can I change the data in an object in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

My desired end result is to change the data in an object in MongoDB using Hyper as my terminal. So far, this is the context of what I'm talking about: the DB, the collections, and the objects.

My database...

```
> show dbs
blogDB      0.000GB
```

Using my database...

```
> use blogDB
switched to db blogDB
```

My collection...

```
> show collections
posts
```

My objects...

```
> db.posts.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f00acc1324fc732401ad2f2"), "title" : "Day 1", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f013318f1fbfe63547d34a6"), "title" : "Day 2", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f01338c8d56ee5070ccd331"), "title" : "Day 3", "content" : "Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. A condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta. Pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl. Urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies 
mi.", "__v" : 0 }
```

What I've tried to use to achieve my desired end result and what occurred when I attempted it...

```
> db.posts.updateOne({title: Day 2}, {$set: {content: Sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus. Lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa.}})
2020-07-05T21:04:04.747-0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing } after property list :
@(shell):1:31

> db.posts.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("5f013318f1fbfe63547d34a6")}, {$set: {content: Sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus. Lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa.}})
2020-07-05T21:11:53.463-0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing } after property list :
@(shell):1:85

> db.posts.replaceOne({_id: ObjectId("5f013318f1fbfe63547d34a6")}, {$set: {content: Sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus. Lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa.}})
2020-07-05T21:51:29.498-0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing } after property list :
@(shell):1:86
```

I also attempted to delete the object so that I could just create a new one in its place. This was the result...

```
> db.posts.deleteOne({title: Day 2})
2020-07-05T21:08:33.748-0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing } after property list :
@(shell):1:31
```

Also, to give further clarification (if necessary): this is the database for a website I developed using MongoDB, Mongoose, NodeJS, Javascript, Express and EJS. This website is a simplified blog website which allows a person to compose a new blog post (via a compose page) which is then added to the aforementioned MongoDB.

This website (currently) does not have a 'delete' or 'edit' button/page - something I'm likely to add in the future. For now, any editing or deleting of posts must be done via MongoDB via a terminal (like the Hyper terminal I'm using).

With that said, I greatly appreciate any help. If there's any further clarification or needed information please feel free to ask. I'm still very much a newbie so I'll do my best to answer as clearly as I can muster.

UPDATE:
Following a suggestion from @thammada.ts I added quotes around the data that was a String type which solved my problem and this was the result...

```
> db.posts.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("5f013318f1fbfe63547d34a6")}, {$set: {content: "Sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus. Lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa."}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [thammada.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1656749/thammada-ts):

> You have to put quotes around values that are `string`s, such as `"Day 2"`, just like how they are represented when you run `db.posts.find()`